# complex listeviewitem image load hang application problem

Tags: android, listviewitem

I am suing Listview and customize listview to display image inside a list item.
I want display image with every search result.

to display complext listeim i am following the following example

http://developer.android.com/guide/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List4.html

inside wrapper class i am initiating new thread for every new list item's image so that i won't dealy the displaying image.

my code is below

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
                   @Override 
                   public void run() {
                Drawable dImage = Util.getImageFromURL(imageURL); 
                getImageIcon().setImageDrawable(dImage);

                }
});
```

mean 10 images initiates 10 different image loading threads other static data is not inside thread.

problem arises when during image loading page application getting hang it should not hang.... any idea what to do ?

[alt text http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/7519/thumbnailx.jpg](http://img509.imageshack.us/img509/7519/thumbnailx.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a background operation to retrieve your images, such as an `AsyncTask`. All your `new Handler().post()` stuff does is delay the work by a nanosecond, not have it be performed in the background.

Also, if you are going to use `Handlers`, just create one.